# Existence of a function extending "even/odd" to infinite sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $F$ be the function that sends a *finite* subset of naturals to the set $\{\text{even}, \text{odd}\}$, according to the parity of its size. Can $F$ be extended to a $G$ on *all* subsets, so that for any (potentially infinite) set $A$ and element $a$ of $A$, we have the following?
$$G(A-\{a\})=\begin{cases}
\text{even}, & \text{if}\; G(A)=\text{odd} \\
\text{odd},  & \text{if}\; G(A)=\text{even}
\end{cases}$$

Transfinite induction doesn't seem to work.

Comment: But when you say that a *finite* set is even/odd, what do you mean? the number of elements of the set?

Comment: yes F sends a finite set to even if the size of the set is even, and same thing for odd

Comment: The set of *even* numbers is infinite and is "bijectable" on the set of *odd*. Thus, are they both odd or even?

Comment: no what i mean is can F be extended to all subsets of the naturals, satisfying the properties I mentioned.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA It looks like the evens and the odds are each both odd *and* even. I'm doubtful there is such a notion of parity.

Comment: If you want to abuse language in this way, you may as well consider every infinite set $X$ *even*, because its cardinality is a multiple of $2$: for $X$ infinite, $2 * |X| = |X|$, so there is a $\kappa$ such that $|X| = 2 * \kappa$.

Comment: To get a contradiction, I think you might want to require that (when $B\subseteq A$) the parity of $A-B$ is Even iff $A,B$ have the same parity and Odd otherwise (right now you only appear to require this ifor finite $B$).   Not sure I am right about that.

Comment: The comments here seem to discuss whether there is a _natural_ or _canonical_ extension that makes intuitive sense. I read the question as asking whether there is _any_ extension that respects the property that any two sets that differ by exactly one element are distinguished by the extended function. Or even that it respects how the finite case works with two disjoint sets and their union. That sounds to me like it can be done, but requires the axiom of choice.

Comment: @copingroidcel: What makes you think this might (or might not) work? Is this a textbook exercise? something you just dreamed-up?

Comment: With the condition as given:  Consider the inifinte subsets of the natural numbers.  We say that two are equivalent iff they differ by a finite set (that is, the set of all natural numbers which are in one but not the other is finite).  Choose a representative of each  equivalence class and assign a parity to that representative arbitrarily.  Then extend the definition of parity to the whole class using the assigned rule.

Comment: @lulu That should be an answer.

Comment: @NoahSchweber  I'll post it as an answer, but I think the interesting question is to extend the notion of parity to allow for infinite subsets.  That is to say, If $B$ is a subset of $A$, then we want the parity of $A-B$ to be the parity of $A$ iff $B$ is even.  My construction doesn't work in that case.

Comment: @Blue it's the infinite version of the prisoner hat puzzle, i was thinking about how to do it. can't believe it was this easy, tried to use the usual method of extending functions by zorn's lemma. thanks for lulu's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a (non-canonical) construction:

If $A,B$ are infinite subsets of $\mathbb N$, we say that they are *equivalent* if they differ by a finite set.  That is, if the set of natural numbers which are in one but not both is finite.  If we think of such subsets as identifying real numbers in $(0,1]$ then equivalence means that the two decimals coincide from some point on.

Choose a representative of each equivalence class and assign its parity arbitrarily (for example, say that all the representatives are Even).  Then extend the notion of parity to the whole class via the given rule.

Note that this notion of parity does not appear to extend to infinite subsets.  That is to say, if $B\subset A$ and $A,B$ are both infinite and the parity of both are known, then we can't infer the parity of the complement, $A-B$.  My sense is that there is no notion of parity which works in this sense, but I am not sure.